# Take figure from big PDF file

Tags: graphics

I am sorry if I am missing something that might be obvious, but after searching for a while I cannot find a simple solution to my problem. I have a big PDF file, from which I want to take some figures (using `trim` option from `\includegraphics`). i want to tell latex to go to page number x of the PDF file to look for the figure. Because it seems useless to dismantle the PDF file page per page, as I have so many figures.

Is that possible to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following 4-page document:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-5]

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{This is figure A}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[6-10]

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-b}
  \caption{This is figure B}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[11-15]

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-c}
  \caption{This is figure C}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Use the `page=<n>` key-value to extract content from a specific page within a larger file via `\includegraphics`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\fbox{\includegraphics[page=2,viewport=100 500 500 700,clip,width=5cm]{lipsum4}}

\end{document}
```